# SeriesCollection.Name to Range? Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I'm attempting to get a proper legend from my excel sheet and I'm attempting to create the legend using the

```
SeriesCollection(1).Name
```

Method in VBA. What I'm doing looks like this

```
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Name = Range(" some range ").Text
```

This however gives me the error of Type Mismatch. Any ideas on what the issue is? Or how I can go about doing this a different way?

Answer (score 2):

Is the range you refer to only one cell? In any case, you can write:

```
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Name = Range("RangeName").Cells(1, 1).Value
```

Comment: No, It's a whole range .. say from A to Z. Let me elaborate the problem. I have data that is several rows below the legend name, so I graph the data and then attempt to add a legend in order to identify the data on the chart.

Comment: + 1 Discarded my answer :)

Comment: @LeeJacobs: If the legend is the first cell in the range, then just use my answer. If it is some other row in the range, you have to change the first number in `Cells` parameter: `.Cells(yourRow, 1)`

Answer (score 0):

If you're referencing an array (range of multiple cells) you'll have to loop through the array and concatenate the individual cell values into a single string variable, and then use that string variable to set the `ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Name`

```
Dim myString as String  'Declare a string variable to concatenate the range values
Dim rng as Range        'This is your range variable
Dim cell as Range       'this will be a cell range within rng

Set rng = Range(" some range ")
For each cell in rng
    myString = myString & cell.Value
Next

ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Name = myString
```